# What does "the sad height" represent in "Do not go gentle into that good night" by Dylan Thomas?

Tags: symbolism, poetry, dylan-thomas

In the final stanza of Dylan Thomas's *Do not go gentle into that good night*, he says,

> And you, my father, there on the sad height,
>   Curse, bless, me now with your fierce tears, I pray.
>   Do not go gentle into that good night.
>   Rage, rage against the dying of the light.

What is meant by "the sad height"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that the "good night" represents death.  I explained this in a [previous answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/421/what-does-the-good-night-symbolize-in-dylan-thomass-do-not-go-gentle-into-th/424#424) where I showed that the poem was written for his dying father.  So the addressee of

> And you, my father, there on the sad height,

is dying.  The speaker is imploring the father not to die, and the father is on the verge of death.  This is what I always took "sad height" to mean.  It's not the best wording, but it had to rhyme with night and light.  [This](http://apeliterature.blogspot.com/2012/10/analysis-do-not-go-gentle-into-that.html) blog thinks it's a biblical reference, referencing the Valley of Despair (last sentence of the 4th paragraph).

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Not my downvote, but it's probably because ([again](http://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/421/what-does-the-good-night-symbolize-in-dylan-thomass-do-not-go-gentle-into-th/424#comment981_424)) this is "a very basic interpretation of a complex poem".